# remove duplicate lines with 2 words

Tags: bash

I have a file where my newdir and finish directories are saved:

```
newdir 26.01.2020_17:28 Directory1
finish 26.01.2020_17:28 Directory1
newdir 26.01.2020_17:29 Directory2
finish 26.01.2020_17:29 Directory2
newdir 26.01.2020_17:28 Directory3
finish 26.01.2020_17:28 Directory4
newdir 26.01.2020_17:29 Directory5
finish 26.01.2020_17:29 Directory3
newdir 26.01.2020_17:28 Directory6
finish 26.01.2020_17:28 Directory6
newdir 26.01.2020_17:29 Directory7
finish 26.01.2020_17:29 Directory7
newdir 26.01.2020_17:28 Directory8
finish 26.01.2020_17:28 Directory9
newdir 26.01.2020_17:29 Directory10
finish 26.01.2020_17:29 Directory11
```

i want to remove all where the directory name and newdir and finish match.
or put differently: Is directory name negotiate with newdir and finish, then remove it in file

example: Directory2 has newdir and finish, then remove both it in file

```
newdir 26.01.2020_17:29 Directory2
finish 26.01.2020_17:29 Directory2
```

unfortunately I have no approach to the solution ..
can someone help me?

Thanks.

Regards

edit:
expected result in the file:

```
finish 26.01.2020_17:28 Directory4
newdir 26.01.2020_17:29 Directory5
newdir 26.01.2020_17:28 Directory8
finish 26.01.2020_17:28 Directory9
newdir 26.01.2020_17:29 Directory10
finish 26.01.2020_17:29 Directory11
```

Comment: Could you please post sample expected output in your post and let us know then

Comment: you've mentioned that you wish to `remove` lines; are you looking for a solution that updates the source file, or do you need something to generate a new file (minus the `removed` lines)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this, but awk might also be a good way.

```
sort -k3 dirlist | uniq -u -f2
```

It will order the file dirlist by the 3rd column, and get only unique lines based on the 3rd column.

**Output**

```
newdir 26.01.2020_17:29 Directory10
finish 26.01.2020_17:29 Directory11
finish 26.01.2020_17:28 Directory4
newdir 26.01.2020_17:29 Directory5
newdir 26.01.2020_17:28 Directory8
finish 26.01.2020_17:28 Directory9
```

**Edit**

With awk (this will also preserve the order)

```
awk '{seen[$3]++; line[++count]=$0; key[count]=$3}
    END{
    for(i=1; i <= count; i++)
        if(seen[key[i]] == 1)
            print line[i]
    }' dirlist
```